# Select Directory error ... delphi 7

Tags: delphi, dialog, delphi-7

```
unit unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,FileCtrl,omnixml,omnixmlutils;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    procedure olddiris(name:string);
    procedure GetPath(name:string);
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  olddir: string; //global variable.

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Tform1.olddiris(name:string);
  begin
    if name = 'trick' then
     olddir:= 'c:\program files'+name;
  end;
procedure Tform1.GetPath(name:string);
  var
    options : TSelectDirOpts;
  begin
    OldDirIs(name);  //returns olddir
    if SelectDirectory(OldDir,options,0) then
      ShowMessage('i got it');
  end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   getpath('trick');
end;

end.
```

Options is TSelectDirOpts = set of TSelectDirOpt;

TSelectDirOpt Standard is {TSelectDirOpt = (
  sdAllowCreate,
  sdPerformCreate,
  sdPrompt
)

gFindDirs is a simple variable that keeps the Name nothing else so i erase it.
The setPath(gFindDirs) just forget it ok i replace it with a simple massage..

When I run it i get an error: the "class Estringlist.error: List index out of bounds(0)";
I try this with the component jvselectdirectory of jvcl library but I get the same thing...
in jvselectdirectory if I left it empty it goes me to the default application folder...

Here is all the program... push the button get the name turn into an existing directory i create before and try to open it with the selectdirectory that's it i get the above error...
FULL CODE nothing else create a form and put a button one event onclick().

Oops Sorry i fix it.... The rush to fix it wrong copy paste...
Help...

Comment: When you run what? You show code that you don't include (`OldDirIs`), a variable that isn't referenced (`gFindDirs`), and use `options` as a param to `SelectDirectory` but don't show the code that sets `options`, and then expect us to solve an `EStringList error` exception without showing code that uses a `TStringList`? "My car does not work. I don't own a car, but what could be wrong?" Please edit your question to make it an actual question that makes sense. As is, it should be closed as nonsense.

Comment: Here is the funny thing my Friend Ken White i don't use any stringlist the error i get i get it from the selectdirectory...

Comment: @azrael11 It looks like we need to spell this out for you. Please post the real code that you are running.

Comment: Your edit is no better. It still isn't the real code. Real code compiles. When you fix the bugs, the errors you describe do not occur.  This is a train wreck of a question which I am now voting to close. It is irredeemable.

Comment: So you say that when you compile this project you dont get and error ... hmmm that is strange bcs recently i add fastmm let me check it

Comment: And what do you mean with "real code" this is all the code... :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3555/discussion-between-azrael11-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: Why can't you paste compilable code?... `procedure olddiris(name);` "missing parameter"..., `TForm1.olddiris` "unsatisfied forward declaration"..., `TForm1.GetPath` "unsatisfied forward declaration"..., `olddir:string` "expected ;"... Anyway, there's no 'List index out of bounds(0)' here. BTW, I think you should put a `\\` between 'program files' and 'trick'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
olddir: string; //global variable

procedure olddiris(name:string);
begin
    if name = 'trick' then
     olddir:= 'c:\program files\'+name;
  end;

procedure MyGetPath(name:string);
  var
    options : TSelectDirOpts;
  begin
    OldDirIs(name);  //returns olddir
    if FileCtrl.SelectDirectory(OldDir,options,0) then
      ShowMessage('i got it');
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
   Mygetpath('trick');
  end;
```

This code runs without error... (Note: changed GetPath -> MyGetPath; added "\" to 'c:\program files')  If the problem still exists, look elsewhere in you code or post more code/info.

Comment: i put it the problem still exists.. i have no other code only this ... but search from here and there i found that maybe is delphi 7 error i try some things and talk later if you find something else just post thank you Bob A

Comment: @azrael11 Change SelectDirectory to FileCtrl.SelectDirectory...

Comment: @azrael11 If you are running it in the IDE the debugger will through up an exception if the file is not found. This is normal.  When you run the exe the file not found exception is handled internally.

Comment: At last i found solution .... haha ... In project>Options>packages i uncheck the build with run time packages and it works... so i search what is the unit that cause that problem and i FOUND it is alpha controls unit that i use in my older project... so the question goes directy to their forum ... Thank you all of them for the patience but you help me a lot now the case is solved from here... i ACCEPT it david... i think you never thougth that and i hope this at close post help people with the same problem...

Comment: What you should have done is written this comment as an answer and accepted that, since this answer does not answer your question.

Comment: Yes david does not answer my question but with good will from other people to have time to spend in a stupid lazy person like me at least give me time to start engines to my brain and think who to find a direction to the solution... now you can close it as you wish...

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your code with

```
procedure GetPath(name:string);  
var  
  options : TSelectDirOpts;   
begin  
  FixedOldDirIs(name);  //returns olddir
  gFindDirs := name;  
  if FixedSelectDirectory(OldDir,options,0) then  
    FixedSetPath(gFindDirs);  
end;
```

That should do the trick (if I understand your question correctly...)

Comment: no my friend but thanks i post a very lazy post... so thanks...